# User ranking position in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a game application, I'm keeping track of the number of games won per user, something like:

```
// table: users
id | username | num_games_won
```

How would I tell a user their overall ranking in terms of num_games_won? For example:

```
   id   | username | num_games_won
-----------------------------------
  723      john          203              
  724      mary          1924
  725      steve         391
```

The rankings would be: mary->0, steve->1, john->2. Given a username, how would I find their ranking number? (I'm using mysql)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try counting the number of users that have more games won that the user you are interested in (by `id` or `username`)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
WHERE num_games_won > (SELECT num_games_won FROM users WHERE id = 723)
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense - if I already know the user id, I don't need to do the sub-select, right? Will this query degrade badly with the more users I get? Say I have 1,000,000 users, and I'm running the query for the last-place user - does mysql have to load all 1,000,000 records to do the count?

Comment: @user291701 - if you already knew the `num_games_won` for the user, you wouldn't need the sub-select. This shouldn't degrade since it only gets a count of records (it won't bring back rows of data for all records).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can do a simple `ORDER BY`.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support the nice analytical functions like `RANK` or `ROWNUMBER` that other databases support, because those would be other potential solutions when the answer isn't as simple as `ORDER BY`.

(edit: you can sort of [cheat and simulate `ROWNUMBER` in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127) thanks to this answer on SO)

In this case, you'd do `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY num_games_won DESC` and the first row would have the most, the second would have second most, etc.

Comment: this solution wouldn't handle ties.

Comment: Ties I think would be something handled on the application side of things. This solution still lists the number of games won in descending order, so they in theory, they would be next to each other.